# Integration around $|z|=1$ counterclockwise once versus clockwise twice

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $C$ being the contour that traces $|z|=1$ counterclockwise once and $D$ is the contour that traces $|z|=1$ clockwise twice.  I would like to know the difference between

$$\oint_C\frac{dz}{\cos{z}}$$

and

$$\oint_D\frac{dz}{\cos{z}}$$

I do know that, by the 'back and forth' theorem, that

$$\oint_D\frac{dz}{\cos{z}}=\oint_{-D}\frac{-dz}{\cos{z}}$$

But I've never done an integral with two times around a particular path.

EDIT:  By Frank Lu's comment, I'd like to also extend this to the following integrals;

$$\oint_C\frac{dz}{\sin{z}}$$

and

$$\oint_D\frac{dz}{\sin{z}}$$

since there is a zero inside the contour, at $z=0$.

Comment: By direct computation, you can show that the zeros of $\cos z$ are precisely $n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$ where $n\in\Bbb{Z}$. This means $\frac{1}{\cos z}$ has no singularity inside $|z|=1$, and thus is analytic. So both integrals equal to $0$.

Comment: So, I did that thing, where I was thinking sin was cos and switched their zeros. I was thinking there was a zero at 0.  jeez that was amateur.  Thank you.  I suppose, for the time being, what if it were $sin,$ not $cos$?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContourWindingNumber.html the concept of winding number can be used to extend this  to arbitrary numbers of clockwise/counterclockwise contours